# Paypal iOS SDK too many calls to /AccessControl/LogRiskMetada

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

I have an iOS app embedding the Paypal SDK (v2.14.2) through CocoaPods. I am only using - at the moment - the sdk as option for login through Paypal.

I am also using New Relic to monitor all the requests sent by my app, and I noticed that the Paypal SDK calls more than **47 requests per minute** the following endpoint:

*api-m.paypal.com - /AccessControl/LogRiskMetadata*.

Do you know why this is happening?

Do you know how I could disable this call from the Paypal SDK?